# In phonegap's childBrowser always shows virtual keyboard when click <a href>

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, javascript-framework

I have a problem with a bug in phonegap on android-4.4 devices if I use childBrowser plugin. But on android 4.0 all is good.

**Phonegap** version - 2.9, **Cordova** version - 3.1.0

When I click on a tag with href attribute virtual keyboard always opens at the same time.
I tried to put e.preventDefault but it is not working. 
Can anybody help me? I suppose it is phonegap's bug.

I can't find any solution. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/QHixCtC2JLY) Is some answers but no really working solution.